# In Scheme/ChezScheme, using a map with display causes to print void after the procedure finishes

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm using `chezscheme 9.5.8`. I created the following function, which receives a string and prints a phrase using that string:

```lisp
> (define (ijustlove str)
    (display
      (string-append "I just love "
                     (string-upcase str)
                     "!!!\n")))
> (ijustlove "bananas")
I just love BANANAS!!!
```

But, if I map the function over a list, it prints `#<void>` (Which is the same as doing `(display (void))` ):

```lisp
> (map ijustlove '("strawberries" "bananas" "grapes"))
I just love STRAWBERRIES!!!
I just love BANANAS!!!
I just love GRAPES!!!
(#<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: `display` prints the string, and returns `#<void>`. `map` creates a list of all the returned values.

Comment: Use `for-each` if you don't need the list of results.

Comment: When a procedure returns `#<void>` to the REPL, that result isn't printed. Compare `(display "hi")` and `(list (display "hi"))`.

Comment: The better way to do this is to split up logic that does something and the side effect. eg. `ijustlove` should perhaps just be the string-append part and *not* display. Then `(map ijustlove '("lisp" "haskell"))` would evaluate to `("I just love LISP!!!" "I just love HASKELL!!!)` and if you wanted to print them you did `(for-each display (map ijustlove  '("lisp" "haskell")))` or `(for-each (λ (v) (display (ijustlove v))) '("lisp" "haskell"))`